# What's the meaning of the $\top$ symbol in a Hoare triple?

Tags: software-verification, hoare-logic

I'm studying program verification and came across the following triple:
$$ \{\top\} \;P \; \{y=(x+1)\} $$
What's the meaning of the $\top$ symbol on the precondition? Does it mean $P$ can take any input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The symbol $\top$, known as *top*, stands for "True". There is also a symbol $\bot$, known as *bottom*, which stands for "False". Top is always true, and bottom is always false. In your case, having a precondition that always holds is the same as having no precondition.

Comment: To be pedantic, I will point out that the meaning of "top" and "bottom" depends on the specific logical system - and maybe some other contexts ;)